# Each Listview item opens up same layout with different content

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity

I have an Activity called TutorialTitels. In that Activity I only have a listview with 5 items in it. Tutorial 1, tutorial 2, etc.
When I click an item - like Tutorial 1 - I want to go to an Activity called Tutorial, that loads up my tutorial screen. The tutorial screen contains for every tutorial 1 TextView where the whole tutorial should come in.

**My problems is:** how do I get different tutorials, based on which ListItem has been pressed in the same layout. I was thinking about

```
if(position == 0)
{
// do stuff
}
else if(position == 1)
{
// do stuff
}
```

But what if I have 100 items, how do I set up the correct ListViewItem to the correct tutorialLayout? This is something I don't get, can you help me with this or give me an example how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the listing activity class to implement `OnItemClickListener`

Then you must implement the `onItemClick` method somewhere inside this activity.

For example, if you keep all tutorials on an `ArrayList<TutorialClass>` named `mTutorials`, do something like:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg3) {

    TutorialClass clickedTutorial = mTutorials.get(position);
    TutorialActivity.tutorial = clickedTutorial;
    Intent i = new Intent(this, TutorialActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

You will need then to add this field on your `TutorialActivity` class:

```
// The tutorial set before creating this activity
public static TutorialClass tutorial;
```